# Prevent Minecraft from synching saved resources

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, xbox-one

My Kid likes Minecraft, and plays on the Xbox One, but for a while now, the game load time is taking 45 minutes to an hour. during which time, the screen is black.
Is this a known issue with a solution? Are others experiencing this?
Other games load up quickly. everything else seems to be working fine.

I looked at the data it was trying to sync, 4GB, and realized there is no way it can upload that much data on my slow internet. I deleted the sync data, and boot time is seconds now. Is there a way to stop Minecraft from syncing data to the cloud?

Comment: There isn't much you can do when it comes to console games, other than try reinstalling the game.

Comment: Not sure if this is relevant but on my Xbox Series X I had some issues with Assassin's Creed and had to force quit the game as there was some cruft being stored in the autoresume mode.

Xbox help docs suggest power cycling the machine as well.

Comment: I looked at the data it was trying to sync, 4GB, and realized there is no way it can upload that much data on my slow internet. I deleted the sync data, and boot time is seconds now. is there a way to stop Minecraft from syncing data to the cloud?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The game is synchronizing save games and local data to the cloud. To prevent this, play offline. If your game can't check the state of the cloud data, it can't sync it.

Also, deleting the data means deleting save states like worlds and save data. Since this is your kid's, make sure to not inadvertently destroy their creations.